# How do I create an endpoint for API upload in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I am working with a client who needs to get me data via a secure endpoint. He would like to use the [Tenstreet](https://resources.tenstreet.com/api/) API and needs me to provide an https url for him to send data to.

I have experience with Google Cloud, but mostly BigQuery, and IAM management. I have looked through documentation about Endpoints, but it is confusing as they seem to all refer to creating APIs as opposed to just using one for data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Expose an endpoint using Cloud Storage, is not possible yet. The usually way to this is with Cloud Functions; this is a serverless solution where you can code an gives you an endpoint for public use.

Then you need to create the function for connecting with the TenStreet API an retrieve the data for the Storage Service that you need.

Google Endpoints is more focus on API design or implementation; provides you an SDK to implement your API with based on a design.